# Fetch data based on month of a quarter in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a table :

```
Month      Data1    Data2

Jan-17       2       3
Feb-17       3       4
Mar-17       2       3
Apr-17       4       1
May-17       1       2
```

The output should  be :

```
Month    Data
Jan-17   Data2(Jan)+Data2(Feb)+Data2(Mar)(3+4+3)
Feb-17   Data1(Jan)+Data2(Feb)+Data2(Mar)(2+4+3)
Mar-17   Data1(Jan)+Data1(Feb)+Data2(Mar)(2+3+3)
```

Quarter starts from Jan, if the month is first month of quarter , output for first month should be should be :Data1 for firstmonth+Data2 for next 2 months

If the month is 2nd month of quarter , output should be Data1 from last month and data2 for 2nd month+data2 for 3rd month

If the month is 3rd month of quarter , output for 3rd month should be Data1 from first month+Data1 from 2nd month +Data2 for 3rd month .

I am using oracle database .
Can someone help .

Comment: Of what datatype is the `Month` column? . Is it stored as character or you have showed only the month component of `DATE` ?

Comment: I have showed month component of Date

Comment: So, are there going to multiple entries in a given month or only single entry?

Comment: originally there were multiple entries but I have grouped them now they appear somewhat like this ,having single entry for each month

Comment: @joe, what results do you expect for rows with 'Apr-17' and 'May-17' values in the "Month" column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a query like this. Make sure you include `NULL` checks for Data1 ,Data2 when records are missing for future dates or past dates and default it to zero if necessary.

```
select To_CHAR(Month,'MON-YY') Month,
        CASE 
                WHEN MOD ( EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM Month ), 3 ) = 1 
                THEN Data2 + LEAD ( Data2 ,1) OVER ( ORDER BY Month ) + LEAD ( Data2 ,2) OVER ( ORDER BY Month )
                WHEN MOD ( EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM Month ), 3 ) = 2 
                THEN LAG(Data1,1) OVER ( ORDER By Month ) + Data2 + LEAD ( Data2 ,1) OVER ( ORDER BY Month )
                WHEN MOD ( EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM Month ), 3 ) = 0 
                THEN LAG(Data1,2) OVER ( ORDER By Month ) + LAG(Data1,1) OVER ( ORDER By Month )+Data2
        END data
FROM 
        Table1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea62e/10)