# How to use lead lag function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written some query to get my resultant result as below :
Note: I have months starting from jan-2016 to jan-2018.
      There are two types, either 'hist' or 'future'
Resultant dataset :
    In this example : let consider combination of id1+id2+id3 as 1,2,3

```
type    month     id1  id2  id3    value
hist    jan-17     1    2   3       10
hist    feb-17     1    2   3       20
future  jan-17     1    2   3       15
future  feb-17     1    2   3       1
hist    mar-17     1    2   3       2
future  apr-17     1    2   3       5
```

My calculation logic depends on the quarter number of month .
For eg . for month of january(first month of quarter) i want the value to be : future of jan + future value of feb + future value of march .
so for jan-17 , output should be : 15+1 + 0(for march there is no corresponding future value)

for the month of feb (2nd month of quarter), value should be : hist of jan + future of feb + future of march i.e 10+1+0(future of march is not available)

Similarly for the month of march , value should be : history of jan + history of feb + future of march i.e 10+20+0(frecast of march no present) .

similarly for april,may.june(depending on quarter number of month)

I am aware of the lead lag function , but I am not able to apply it here
Can someone please help

Comment: "I have written some query...".  Where's your query????  I don't see it.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. What actual value do you want to show for jan-17, and where is the 20 coming from for the 'future' value for feb-17 - because feb-17 is in the future relative to jan-17 even though that is also 'hist'? Why only feb-17 and mar-17, are you always looking for 3-month windows? Why isn't the 'hist' value for jan-17 relevant? Please explain your logic in a lot more detail, and adding more sample data and expected results would probably help too.

Comment: Hi Alex !! I have edited the question .Please let me know if it understandable now

Comment: I think I answered one of your questions, quite similar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482938/fetch-data-based-on-month-of-a-quarter-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

I would not mess with lag, this can all be done with a group by if you convert your dates to quarters:

```
WITH
    dset
    AS
        (SELECT DATE '2017-01-17' month, 5 VALUE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATE '2017-02-17' month, 6 VALUE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATE '2017-03-25' month, 7 VALUE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATE '2017-05-25' month, 4 VALUE
           FROM DUAL)
  SELECT SUM (VALUE) value_sum, TO_CHAR (month, 'q') quarter, TO_CHAR (month, 'YYYY') year
    FROM dset
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (month, 'q'), TO_CHAR (month, 'YYYY');
```

This results in:

```
VALUE_SUM QUARTER YEAR
18        1       2017
 4        2       2017
```

We can use an analytic function if you need the result on each record:

```
SELECT SUM (VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (month, 'q'), TO_CHAR (month, 'YYYY')) quarter_sum, month, VALUE
  FROM dset
```

This results in:

```
QUARTER_SUM MONTH     VALUE
18          1/17/2017   5
18          2/17/2017   6
18          3/25/2017   7
 4          5/25/2017   4
```

Make certain you include year, you don't want to combine quarters from different years.

Comment: Hi Brian !! Thanks for the answer ,but I think you misunderstood my question . I have sum it up based on the type ,whether it is history or future

Comment: Changed my mind, don't know how to delete a comment.

Comment: @joe I am not understanding your comment. My code sums the values by quarter. Your labels 'FUTURE' and 'HISTORY' don't mean anything in the context you defined in your statement "*for the month of feb (2nd month of quarter), value should be : hist of jan + future of feb + future of march i.e 10+1+0(future of march is not available)*". After re-reading your question, you are simply asking for a sum by quarter, which is what my code does.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as said in one of the comments.. the trick lies in another question of yours & the corresponding answer. Well... it goes somewhat like this..

```
with 
x as
    (select 'hist' type, To_Date('JAN-2017','MON-YYYY') ym , 10 value from dual union all
    select 'future' type, To_Date('JAN-2017','MON-YYYY'), 15 value from dual union all
    select 'future' type, To_Date('FEB-2017','MON-YYYY'), 1 value from dual),
y as
    (select * from x Pivot(Sum(Value) For Type in ('hist' as h,'future' as f))),
    /* Pivot for easy lag,lead query instead of working with rows..*/
z as
    (
        select ym,sum(h) H,sum(f) F from (
            Select y.ym,y.H,y.F from y
            union all
            select add_months(to_Date('01-JAN-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'),rownum-1) ym, 0 H, 0 F 
            from dual connect by rownum <=3 /* depends on how many months you are querying... 
            so this dual adds the corresponding missing 0 records...*/
        ) group by ym
    )
select 
ym,
Case
    When MOD(Extract(Month from YM),3) = 1
    Then F + Lead(F,1) Over(Order by ym) + Lead(F,2) Over(Order by ym)
    When MOD(Extract(Month from YM),3) = 2
    Then Lag(H,1) Over(Order by ym) + F + Lead(F,1) Over(Order by ym)
    When MOD(Extract(Month from YM),3) = 3
    Then Lag(H,2) Over(Order by ym) + Lag(H,1) Over(Order by ym) + F
End Required_Value
from z
```